# Trying to implement some pseudo code, algorithm

Tags: java

I'm working on a homework problem that can be done in java or pseudo code, I'm trying the java code way.

Background: There exists a machine that makes iphone casing. The machine has three possible cases that it can make, each of which have different paint costs. Given original amounts of paint, return the integer value of the minimum amount of cases that can be made.

Here is my code,

```
public class ProblemFour
    {   
        //Array entries represent cost for red, green and blue respectively. 
        int[] classicCost = {4, 1, 1};
        int[] coolCost    = {3, 2, 1};
        int[] modernCost  = {1, 3, 2};
        String[] names = {"classic", "cool" , "modern"};
        int red;
        int green;
        int blue;
        Random generator = new Random();
        int pick = generator.nextInt(3);        
    public int minPhone(int r, int g, int b, String mold)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        if (r > 1 && g > 1 && b > 1 && mold.equals("classic"))
        {
            counter += 1;
            red   = r - classicCost[0];
            green = g - classicCost[1];
            blue  = b - classicCost[2];
            Random generator = new Random();
            int pick = generator.nextInt(3);
            counter += minPhone(red, green, blue, names[pick]);
        }
        else if (r > 1 && g > 1 && b > 1 && mold.equals("cool"))
        {
            counter += 1;
            red   = r - coolCost[0];
            green = g - coolCost[1];
            blue  = b - coolCost[2];
            Random generator = new Random();
            int pick = generator.nextInt(3);
            counter += minPhone(red, green, blue, names[pick]);
        }
        else if (r > 1 && g > 1 && b > 1 && mold.equals("modern"))
        {
            counter += 1;
            red   = r - modernCost[0];
            green = g - modernCost[1];
            blue  = b - modernCost[2];
            Random generator = new Random();
            int pick = generator.nextInt(3);
            counter += minPhone(red, green, blue, names[pick]);
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        ProblemSetThree.ProblemFour example = new ProblemFour();
        String[] names = {"classic", "cool" , "modern"};
        Random generator = new Random();
        int pick = generator.nextInt(3);
        //System.out.println(pick);
        int testCount = example.minPhone(6, 7, 7, names[pick]);
        System.out.println(testCount);


    }
}
```

So in the example, the correct answer is 2, not 3. My code will sometimes give either. How do I make sure that it only returns the minimum number?

After this, I need to turn this into a dynamic programing program.
I'm not interested in optimizating or software engineering aspects of this code, only that it returns the correct answer.

Thank you.

Comment: What is downvoter's rationale? This is my code, not something copied from a book or assignment.

Comment: maybe it looks a bit too `homework`ish..? dunno

Comment: It says in the first line that its part of a hw assignment. This is a specific programming question. I don't mind downvotes, but hit and runs are annoying.

Comment: Look into knapsack problems (amount of paint = capacity, paint for a piece = weight)

Comment: The algorithm you want is often called box packing. Loads of examples about.

Comment: @RC, TonyHopkinson Thank you both, I hadn't heard of either algos before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this looks like homework, just a couple of tips:

- You should not need random numbers for this.

The dynamic programming solution would be:

- General idea:

  - If I build a case A, whats the minimum of cases I could still build in the future?
  - If I build a case B, whats the minimum of cases I could still build in the future?
  - If I build a case C, whats the minimum of cases I could still build in the future?
- Choose the minimum of these cases and repeat.

Recursively, that would be:

```
//costs
int[] A = {4, 1, 1};
int[] B = {3, 2, 1};
dint[] C = {1, 3, 2};

public int minPhone(int r, int g, int b){
    int minA = 0;
    int minB = 0;
    int minC = 0;
    if(r-A[0] > 0,g-A[1] > 0,r-A[2] > 0){ //can I make a case A?
        minA = minPhone(r-A[0],g-A[1],r-A[2]);
    }
    if(r-B[0] > 0,g-B[1] > 0,r-B[2] > 0){ //can I make a case B?
        minB = minPhone(r-B[0],g-B[1],r-B[2]);
    }
    if(r-C[0] > 0,g-C[1] > 0,r-C[2] > 0){ //can I make a case C?
        minC = minPhone(r-C[0],g-C[1],r-C[2]);
    }
    minABC = min(minA,min(minB,minC));
    return minABC;
}
```

Now, you need to come up with a version that does the same thing, but not recursively. That would be the dynamic programming. Hint: Think of creating a large spreadsheet like the recursive solution, but just use an array to do it without recursion.

Comment: Thank you. The random numbers were because, i forgot to mention, the machine in the problem is broken and it randomly picks phone cases to build.

Comment: Well if the machine is broken then the number of cases it produces will always be greater or equal to the minimum, so if you need the minimum then the "broken" doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Well the algorithm I gave you calculates the minimum. The idea behind dynamic programming is to start thinking backwards/recursively. Suppose you had only 0 paint, what would the minimum be? Now suppose you had enough paint to make just either 1 case A or 2 cases of B: Which of the cases A,B or C would you rather make if you want to have a minimum amount of cases in the end?